# How to use KeyVault secret for Logic App SQL Connection String

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a Azure Logic App, which is connecting to the SQL Server Database. Currently I am saving the connection string in configurations section of the logic app.
I am planning to use the azure keyvault and  get the connection string from there.
I have gone through the online articles which tells about the keyvault connector. but I am not looking for that.
I want to use the Keyvault secret for my sql server connections in the Azure Logic App.

[image]

I have also tried with the SQL GetRows as you can see below but I don't see any connection string textbox, where I can use the GetSecret Action Result
[image]

Comment: How are you “not looking for that”? Why can you not use this action? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/keyvault/#get-secret   It’s exactly what you’re wanting by the sounds of it.

Comment: Because that give me the secret in the action and i need to initialise my connection string for sql queries in app settings. If there’s a way to use that action result as a connection string for sql server, please let me know how to do it. I am new to Logic Apps

Comment: I understand what you want now.  Can you update your question to show the action with any sensitive data obfuscated/blurred?  I want to check something based on that.

Comment: Connection strings are not secrets (unless they contains passwords in which case you need to revisit your authentication approach)., they are configuration. I disagree with putting non-sensitive configuration data into keyvault. It makes no sense

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The connectionstring has username and password as well. And Its not Azure Sql Server so we can not directly integrate it. If you can suggest something in this scenario, it will be a great help.

Comment: @Skin I have updated the question, Please have a look, if you can suggest something

Comment: I suggest moving to windows authentication if possible.

Comment: ... although windows authentication is not an option if connecting from logic apps.

Comment: It’s a part of the definition therefore, there’s no simple solution. You can’t just flick it during the run time, it’s a design time thing. Happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As @Skin mentioned You can use Azure Key Vault's Get Secret action in your case. For this search for `Azure Key Vault` Connector and select `Get secret` action.

[image]

Now you need to establish a connection to your Key Vault by providing your Vault name and Tenant.

[image]

Then select the secret that you want to retrieve

[image]

After you run the logic app you can see the value that got stored in your key vault.

[image]

In Vault:-

[image]

Comment: This would give me the value in the actions. But i need to use that in the configuration of the logic app.
 how would I use the secret as a connection string for sql server? Connection strings are stored in the configurations of the logic app.

Comment: You can add the SQL Server Connection in the next step and use the Secret Value that you are retrieving from the `Get Secret` Connection. Please try checking the attached image https://i.imgur.com/B6Qd34C.png.

Comment: Here is the output https://i.imgur.com/lyoYOUZ.png and https://i.imgur.com/VdCcLdu.png

Comment: In the GetRows, I don't see the connection string textbox on my side. As you can see the above picture.

Comment: The GetRows action gives you the data in your database table and this has nothing to do with the connection string

Comment: Can you please help us understand what connection string are you retrieving and why are you retrieving. I mean for what purpose you are retrieving the connection string

Comment: This is what I am doing:
1. when http URL is hit
2. I am updating the SQL Rows through Execute SQL Query (For this SQL Query, I am using a connection string in the configuration of the Logic App)

What I want is,  
For the SQL Server Connection String, I want to save the Connection String in the Azure Keyvault and use it to make the Execute Query work.  
Now as per the proposed solutions up there, I am getting the keyvault secret in one of the actions, But I can not use that result in the connection string configuration as you can see the screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The connection strings are saved as application settings of the Logic App.
[Change connection string in configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53ak9.png)

There you can edit the app setting related to your connection string (`sql_connectionString` in my case) with `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=<keyvault name>.vault.azure.net/secrets/<name of your secret>)` or optionally `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=<keyvault name>.vault.azure.net/secrets/<name of your secret>/<version>)`.

Once you save your application settings, you will see a green check and `Key vault Reference` in the source column of your application setting.
[Key vault Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM7mj.png)

Comment: Please edit post and add text of this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/53ak9.png, please read how to ask question in help center for give best feedback : https://stackoverflow.com/help